# Increasing a sequence count in a text file with batch command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, text, sequence

Like the title says, I'd very imply like to execute a simple command that increases a sequence count in a .txt file.  For instance, every time I push a hotkey assigned to said batch file, it increases the number in the text file by n+1.  So if the number in the file is 24, running the script increases it to 25.  Is a batch script capable of this, or should it be run through VBS or Powershell?

I know it sounds simple in theory, but I've no idea how to actually implement a task like this through existing tools

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PowerShell script that will increment ~\counter.txt:

```
$counterFile = "~\counter.txt"
if ( !(Test-Path ~\counter.txt) ) { "0" > $counterFile }
Set-Content $counterFile ([int](Get-Content $counterFile) + 1)
```